# how do i create a dictionary within a nested for loop for django database query?

Tags: python, django

I have the following code;

## views.py

```
def render_blog_topics(request, topic):
    
    categories = get_list_or_404(Category, name=topic)
    
    """for category in categories:
        for topic in category.topics.all():
            topic_posts += Post.objects.all().filter(topic = topic).order_by('topic')
            print Post.objects.all().filter(topic = topic).order_by('topic').query
            print topic_posts"""
    all_data = []
    all_topics = Topic.objects.all()
    def loop_topic():
        for topic in all_topics:
            current_data = {}
            current_posts = []
            current_posts.append(Post.objects.filter(Q(topic=topic))) 
            # append more posts based on query here like Q(categorie__topic = each_topic) or something
        current_data['topic'] = topic
        current_data['posts'] = current_posts
        all_data.append(current_data)      
    
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category= loop_topic())
    
    print Post.objects.filter(category= loop_topic())                

    data = {
            'categories': categories,
            'TopicsForm': TopicsForm(),
            'all_data' : all_data
             
            }
    print all_data 
    
    return render(request, 'blog_topics.html',data)
```

Basically what the data var already contains is used for tags concerning navigation elemnts and other parts of the site.

What i am trying to accomplish is for each topic in

```
        for category in categories:
        for topic in category.topics.all():
            print topic
```

I want to get all the posts based off the topic currently in the loop and have it build a variable that i can place in data.

For example

Topic1 ---> All posts related to topic1
Topic2 ---> ALl posts related to topic2
.....so on so fourth

How do i go about building a single varaible that will hold the topic and all the posts associated with it so that i can just loop through it in the template;

```
{% for each topic %}
{% for each post in topic %}

{{ obj.title }}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

(just trying to convey the logic of what im trying to do).

## solution

templating.py

```
             {% for each_item in all_data %}
             <div id="{{ each_item.topic }}" class="content_list">
             <a class="title" href="">{{ each_item.topic }}</a>
                <div class="list_container">
                    <ul>
                     {% for posts in each_item.posts %}
                        {% for post in posts %}
                        <li class="python">
                            <a href="">{{ post.title }}<br/> 
                            <span class="date_comments">{{ post.date_created }} | 
                            <span class="comments">12</span></span></a>
                        </li>
                         {% endfor %}
                     {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                </div>                       
             </div>
             {% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
    categories = get_list_or_404(Category, name=topic)           
all_data = []
all_topics = Topic.objects.all()
category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category = categories[0])
print category_posts
for each_topic in all_topics:
    current_data = {}
    current_posts = []
    current_posts.append(category_posts.filter(Q(topic=each_topic))) 
    # append more posts based on query here like Q(categorie__topic = each_topic) or something
    current_data['topic'] = each_topic
    current_data['posts'] = current_posts
    all_data.append(current_data) 
data = {
        'categories': categories,
        'TopicsForm': TopicsForm(),
        'all_data' : all_data
         
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it this way ...

```
all_data = []
all_topics = Topic.objects.all()
categorie_posts = Post.objects.filter(categorie=categories)
for each_topic in all_topics:
    current_data = {}
    current_posts = []
    current_posts.append(categorie_posts.filter(Q(topic=each_topic)) 
    # append more posts based on query here like Q(categorie__topic = each_topic) or something
    current_data['topic']=each_topic
    current_data['posts'] = current_posts
    all_data.append(current_data)
```

now in template

```
 {% for each_item in all_data %}
     {% each_item.topic %}
     {% for each_post in each_item.posts %}
         {% each_post.title %}
         {% each_post.content %}
     {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: H]i, this seems to be leading me in the right direction. I however have run into a few problems. The for loop is giving an indentation error so in order to try and fix that i put all the for loop logic into a function loop_topic(), and then called category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category= loop_topic()). In my database i have 2 posts marked as the same topic however the template is rendering each topic as a separate item and i am unable to access its attributes using each_post.title etc. Ill edit my post above to include what i have done as per your code

Comment: hi i think there is an error in my code above .. i fixed it now .. i forgot to finish the categorie_posts query and use that variable

Comment: hey, thanks it worked pretty much exactly as you posted but I had to make one minor changed in the templating code. THere seems to be an extra tier in posts [[]]. Is this by design? Therefore you need to loop into posts one extra time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this way. Declare a dict and a list for ex:-

```
topic_dict = {}
topic_list = []
```

Inside your loop build the dictionary, like

```
topic_dict = { 'title': topic['title'], 'author': topic['author'] }
```

Then inside the same loop append this dictionary to a list like

```
topic_list.append(topic_dict)
```

So finally it will give you a list containing dictionaries, which you can loop through easily inside the template.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Sorry I dont quite follow. Ive edited my post above to show the query i am going to be running. This query returns a query set but i am having difficulty logically understanding how to build the object(s) I can place into the existing dictionary. The query builds a query set but i dont know how to place this into the appropriate places within the dict and how to reset the variables so i can generate the next topic posts. Title + other fields are automatically generated as part of the queryset i understand that.